# Custom YouTubePlayer in Flutter Flow | Loading Video Issue

Tags: flutter, flutterflow

I'm trying to make a custom YouTube player that makes users watch the video until compeltion and then update an app state variable in flutter flow. It renders the thumbnail of the video on my flutterflow project but gets stuck on loading the video and never plays.

```
// Automatic FlutterFlow imports
import '/backend/backend.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_theme.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_util.dart';
import '/custom_code/widgets/index.dart'; // Imports other custom widgets
import '/flutter_flow/custom_functions.dart'; // Imports custom functions
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// Begin custom widget code
// DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY THE CODE ABOVE!

import 'package:youtube_player_flutter/youtube_player_flutter.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';

class CustomYoutubePLayer extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomYoutubePLayer({
    Key? key,
    this.width,
    this.height,
    required this.videoURL,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final double? width;
  final double? height;
  final String videoURL;

  @override
  _CustomYoutubePLayerState createState() => _CustomYoutubePLayerState();
}

class _CustomYoutubePLayerState extends State<CustomYoutubePLayer> {
  late YoutubePlayerController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _controller = YoutubePlayerController(
        initialVideoId: YoutubePlayer.convertUrlToId(widget.videoURL) ?? '',
        flags: YoutubePlayerFlags(
          autoPlay: true,
          disableDragSeek: true, // Disable scrubbing
          loop: false,
          isLive: false,
          forceHD: false,
          enableCaption: true,
        ));
    // )..addListener(_videoListener);
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return YoutubePlayer(
      controller: _controller,
      showVideoProgressIndicator: false,
      progressIndicatorColor: Colors.blueAccent,
      bottomActions: [
        CurrentPosition(),
        ProgressBar(isExpanded: false),
      ],
      onReady: () {
        // Perform actions when the player is ready
        _controller.play();
        FFAppState().update(() {
          //check to see of on ready is being called
          setState(() => FFAppState().CustomWidget = true);
        });
      },
      onEnded: (data) {
        //update VideoFinished AppState variable
        FFAppState().update(() {
          setState(() => FFAppState().VideoFinished = true);
        });
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

I've tried messing with the onReady and initState methods and i still haven't found a solution